# Что лучше использовать RowSet или ResultSet с несколькими statement в многопоточной среде?

Tags: java, многопоточность, jdbc

Есть приложение, в котором выполняются запросы к БД (mySql).

Требуется выполнить несколько запросов к базе с одновременным анализом предоставленных ими результатов.

Если использую ResultSet, необходимо использовать несколько Statement.
Если использую RowSet, достаточно одного Statement.

В однопоточной среде с RowSet выполняется дольше (в среднем 00:02:627),
с ResultSet с несколькими Statement быстрее (в среднем 00:02:427).

Далее буду строить многопоточную среду, не будет ли мне дорого стоить ResultSet с несколькими Statement в каждом потоке?

Как это все лучше архитектурно построить?

Comment: а вы напишите и замерьте

Comment: Лучше вснго использовать фетч стратегию